# Silverlight - Determine visibility using multiple bindings

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding, silverlight-4.0

I currently have a simple class that holds various forms of data, I'll call it `MyData` for the purposes of this question. The class will usually be created in xaml under a container's resource section. It currently has a `DependencyProperty` named `Show` that signifies whether its data should be visible in the UI. A common use of this resource would be to template a `TextBlock` to show the data and bind `Show` to its `Visibility` using a converter. The value of `Show` itself usually comes from another `DependencyProperty` (typically in the ViewModel for MVVM implementations). I have an example shown below.

```
<navigation:Page.Resources>
    <ViewModel x:Name="MyModel"/>
    <MyData Data="Some Sample Data" Show="{Binding ModelValue, ElementName=MyModel}"/>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text={Binding Data} Visibility="{Binding Show, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</navigation:Page.Resources>
```

The scenario above is obviously a simplified version of what I am currently working on, but it currently works perfectly. However, I need to allow multiple bindings to affect the data's visibility. To clarify, if and only if all values are true then the data should be shown. So, the MyData xaml from above would look more like this:

```
<MyData Data="Some Sample Data">
    <MyData.Show>
        <AnotherClass Value="{Binding ModelValue1, ElementName=MyModel}"/>
        <AnotherClass Value="{Binding ModelValue2, ElementName=MyModel}"/>
    </MyData.Show>
</MyData>
```

My first thought was to make `Show` an `ObservableCollection<bool>`, but it doesn't keep track of whether its items' values change, only if the items themselves change. When 'ModelValue1', for example, would change from true to false, the collection's `CollectionChanged` event would not be raised. So, I need a way to utilize multiple bindings to determine something's visibility.

I realize this is a fairly long question, but its kind of a complicated one so I tried to be as detailed as needed. Please feel free to ask me to clarify anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your idea with `ObservableCollection<bool>` might actually work fine, however with a small amendment. I would create something like `ObservableCollection<SomeBoolEncapsulation>` where `SomeBoolEncapsulation` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. When value of the inner bool of the `SomeBoolEncapsulation` changes just raise property changed. When you receive `CollectionChanged` event from your `ObservableCollection` attach/detach handlers to the `PropertyChanged` of the collection items, that way you know when bool values change. Then when binding to viewmodel's bool properties use a converter that will encapsulate the bool from VM into a `SomeBoolEncapsulation`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought it should work too. I guess I'm doing something wrong. Could one of you look at this [sample application](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26625851/SampleApp.zip) and let me know what I am doing wrong? It should hide and show the textblocks based on the state of the target values.

Comment: When binding to target values you use `ElementName=MyModel` when you should be using `Source={StaticResource MyModel}` instead. I've checked this on the app you've posted and it works like a charm.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the quick reply. What is the difference between `ElementName` and `Source`? `ElementName` usually works, why doesn't it work in this case?

Comment: `ElementName` is used to bind to UI elements (elements of Visual Tree). `Source` is used to point to any object though it's usually used for Window/Page/Control resources. You've created your VM as well as other items as resources of the user control so they are not elements of the Visual Tree (just normal instances placed inside control's resource dictionary).